# Determine PostGIS geography polygon orientation

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, spherical-geometry

How can you determine the orientation of a PostGIS `geography` polygon?  I'm looking/hoping for a function that would tell me which side is the interior (left or right) as you traverse the vertices of the outer shell in order.

I have seen the [`ST_Orientation`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Orientation.html) function, but it only works for `geometry`.  I have also seen the [`ST_ForceRHR`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_ForceRHR.html) and [`ST_ForceLHR`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_ForceLHR.html) functions.  But again, they only work for `geometry`.

I have data that wraps around the poles, so naive casting to `geometry` won't work for me.  (Or at least I don't think so.  Maybe this isn't true.)

I'm a reasonably good programmer, so if no such function exists then an algorithm outline would be fine too.

Comment: A reliable algorithm is not possible, because polylines on the sphere merely divide it into two pieces; neither one of them is distinguished (the way the infinite component in the plane would be).  Let's hope an accessible orientation property is stored with the polygon.

Comment: @whuber: If I remember correctly, PostGIS defines the interior to be the "smaller" of the two pieces of the sphere(-oid).  (And that happens to work for me... none of my polygons cover more than half the sphere.)  Though I can't seem to find a reference to that fact any more.  And I don't see a way to find out which side that represents.